# Why doesn't the status of a task change to canceled after cancel is called by CancellationTokenSource

Tags: c#, .net

I made a task to count the number, the task will receive the cancel request after 5 seconds, however after the task is cancelled I checked the status of task.  The status of task is still running.  Why?  The sample code is below:

```
  var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(5000);//Request Cancel after 5 seconds
        var newTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(state =>
        {
            try
            {
                int i = 1;
                var token = (System.Threading.CancellationToken)state;
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                    i++;
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }

            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
            }


        }, cts.Token, cts.Token);


        try
        {
            newTask.Wait(10000, cts.Token);

        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Catch:"+ newTask.Status);//The status is Running
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with that code:

1. `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` does exactly what the name says, it throws an exception. Since you use a `try/catch` block to catch it you might as well just return from the task. The task state after the "cancellation" won't be `Faulted` because the framework doesn't see the exception.
2. You are using `Wait` with the same cancellation token. This means as soon as the 5 seconds are done the `Wait` will be cancelled and the catch block will be executed. At this time the task may or may not be cancelled.

What you should do is getting rid of the `try/catch/finally` in the task's body and remove the token from the call to `Wait`: `newTask.Wait(10000)`.

---

Full code:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(5000);//Request Cancel after 5 seconds
var newTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(state =>
{
    int i = 1;
    var token = (System.Threading.CancellationToken)state;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        i++;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}, cts.Token, cts.Token);

try
{
    newTask.Wait(10000);
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Catch:"+ newTask.Status);
}
```

---

LINQpad output:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   Catch:Canceled

Comment: I try your suggestion,but the this time the program is paused due to the exception thrown by the task body(because it has not been catch),so i can not inspect the status of the task,i`m afraid that i may have some misunderstanding,can you give me the code?

Comment: I copy your code and run it in the visual studio 2013 as a console application,but i don`t have the output as you are,my program is paused due to the exception in the task body

Comment: @BlueSteel This can happen if you set the debugging to break when an exception is thrown. Reseting the exception settings removes that (Debug, Exceptios, Reset all), and the debugger only breaks if an exception is uncaught.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921984/stop-visual-studio-from-breaking-on-exception-in-tasks offer a solution,my problem is solved .Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try to print status to console outside of the catch block. At the point you printing status CancellationPended and Exception throwed, but the state changes right after the catch block execution is finished.

Comment: You are right. There is no repeatable behavior: some runs print status "RanToCompleted", some runs print "Running".