# Visual studio breaks on exception that IS handled with unhandled exception dialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, unhandled-exception

My code calls a WCF service that is current not running.  So we should expect the [`EndPointNotFoundException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.endpointnotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx).  The using statement tries to [`Close()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.ichannel.close(v=vs.110).aspx) the faulted connection which causes a [`CommunicationObjectFaultedException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.communicationobjectfaultedexception(v=vs.110).aspx) which is excepted.  This exception is caught in a try catch block surrounding the using block:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            using (ChannelFactory<IDummyService> unexistingSvc = new ChannelFactory<IDummyService>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "net.pipe://localhost/UnexistingService-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()))
            {
                using (IClientChannel chan = (unexistingSvc.CreateChannel() as IClientChannel))
                {
                    (chan as IDummyService)?.Echo("Hello");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (EndpointNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Expected");
        }
        catch (CommunicationObjectFaultedException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Expected: caused by closing channel that has thrown EndPointNotFoundException");
        }
    }
}
```

*Note the service EndPoint uses a fresh Guid so it will never have a service listening.*

`IDummyService` is:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IDummyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Echo(string e);
}
```

This causes the Visual Studio debugger (Visual Studio Professional 2017 15.4.1) to break with an "Exception Unhandled" popup:
[image: Screen shot: Debugger breaking with Exception Unhandled popup]
The exception on which Visual Studio breaks is `System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException` which **is** caught in the code.

Stepping to continue execution shows that `catch(CommunicationObjectFaultedException ex)` is reached.  Using LinqPad to run the demo also shows that the exception is caught as expected.

I also tried explicitly (double) closing the channel instead of using the `using`-block:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            using (ChannelFactory<IDummyService> unexistingSvc = new ChannelFactory<IDummyService>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "net.pipe://localhost/UnexistingService-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()))
            {
                IDummyService chan = null;
                try
                {
                    chan = unexistingSvc.CreateChannel();
                    chan.Echo("Hello");
                }
                catch (EndpointNotFoundException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Expected: {ex.Message}");
                }
                finally
                {
                    try
                    {
                        (chan as IClientChannel)?.Close();
                    }
                    catch (CommunicationObjectFaultedException ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Caused by Close: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (EndpointNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Expected");
        }
        catch (CommunicationObjectFaultedException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Expected: caused by closing channel that has thrown EndPointNotFoundException");
        }
    }
}
```

This still causes the debugger to break on the `Close` statement.

My Exception Settings has `System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException` unchecked.  (When it is checked Visual studio breaks as expected and with the "Exception Thrown" dialog instead of the "Exception Unhandled" dialog).

When I enable "Options"\"Debugging"\"General"\"Enable Just My Code" the debugger does not break.  However, I have `async` methods where the exception should leave my code and I later catch the exception when `await`ing the `Task`.  For these methods I need "Enable Just My Code" unchecked; see [Stop visual studio from breaking on exception in Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16921984/814206).

With "Using the New Exception Helper" disabled (as suggested by [Jack Zhai-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6601554/jack-zhai-msft)) Visual Studio still breaks and it shows
[image: Screenshot exception dialog when "Using the New Exception Helper" is disabled]
The dialog provides some additional information:

> The exception is not caught before it crosses a *managed/native* boundary.

I suspect that the using block probably introduces this managed/native boundary.

What causes the debugger to break by mistake and how to make the debugger not break neither or handled `CommunicationObjectFaultedException`s nor on later handler `async` exceptions?

Comment: If you disable debugging option "Use the New Exception Helper" under TOOLS->OPTION->Debugging->General in VS2017, how about the result?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I tested with "Use the New Exception Helper" disabled and included the results in the question.  The old exception dialogue gives some new avenues to try in solving the problem.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT thanks, your suggestion helped me solve the problem via correct settings.  Posting an answer now.

Comment: Glad to know that it was helpful for you, I add it as the helpful answer, of course, if you have other useful information to replenish it, you could just edit that answer. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Close()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.iclientchannel.close(v=vs.110).aspx)-ing a [`Faulted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.communicationstate(v=vs.110).aspx) [`IClientChannel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.iclientchannel(v=vs.110).aspx) causes a [`CommunicationObjectFaultedException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.communicationobjectfaultedexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ```
> public void Close(TimeSpan timeout)
> {
>     ...
>     switch (originalState)
>     {
>         case CommunicationState.Created:
>         case CommunicationState.Opening:
>         case CommunicationState.Faulted:
>             this.Abort();
>             if (originalState == CommunicationState.Faulted)
>             {
>                 throw TraceUtility.ThrowHelperError(this.CreateFaultedException(), Guid.Empty, this);
>             }
>             break;
>         ...
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```

-- (See [CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan) line #299](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/CommunicationObject.cs,299) in the [.NET framework 4.7 reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/)).

The `using`-block is translated to `try { ... } finally { Dispose(); }` and [`Dispose()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) calls [`Close()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.iclientchannel.close(v=vs.110).aspx) when the block is left.  The proxy returned by [`CreateChannel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575250(v=vs.110).aspx) is implemented via [`RealProxy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy(v=vs.110).aspx) ([src](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/remoting/realproxy.cs,2e1217e22354c511)) and [`RemotingServices.CreateTransparentProxy()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/remoting/remotingservices.cs,61aac7041ef84f3d) these proxy combine managed and unmanaged code, which might cause the exception crossing the boundary.

The combination of settings (in TOOLS->OPTIONS->Debugger->General):

- ☑ Break when Exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries
- ☐ Enable Just My Code

Causes Visual Studio to break showing either: the new non-modal exception popup "Exception Unhandled": 
[image: Screenshot: Visual Studio: Exception Unhandled (New Exception Handler)] or the modal dialog:
[image: Screenshot: Visual studio breaking on exception that crosses AppDomain or managed/native boundary]

The [`CommunicationObjectFaultedException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.communicationobjectfaultedexception(v=vs.110).aspx) starts in 'Not My Code'; it crosses an managed/unmanaged or AppDomain boundary while still being in 'Not My Code'; and finally enters 'My Code' where it is handled by the `catch`-block (but Visual Studio has already halted the excuting at this point).
Since the exception starts in 'Not My Code' and remains there when crossing the boundary, selecting the option "Enable Just My Code" causes Visual studio to not break on the exception even when it crosses the AppDomain or managed/unmanaged boundary.
Deselecting "break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries" also causes Visual Studio to not break on the exception.

## This gives two solutions/workarounds

- Choose a different combination of **"Break when Exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries"** and **"Enable Just My Code"**
- Do **not** use a `using`-block for the [`IClientChannel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.iclientchannel(v=vs.110).aspx) and check [`IClientChannel.State`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.icommunicationobject.state(v=vs.110).aspx) before [`Close()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.iclientchannel.close(v=vs.110).aspx)-ing.  As is done in [What is the best workaround for the WCF client `using` block issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/573872/814206)

Comment: I had the same problem with EndPointNotFoundException. This setting fixed it for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The new Exception feature was in VS2017, we could disable debugging option "Use the New Exception Helper" under TOOLS->OPTION->Debugging->General which could provide you the old Exception messages, you could visit it.

The old Exception Message shows that the Exception crosses a managed/native boundary:
[image: Screenshot exception dialog when "Using the New Exception Helper" is disabled]

Check "Break when Exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries" under  TOOLS->OPTION->Debugging->General.  Disable "Break when Exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries" to avoid Visual Studio breaking on the OP's situation (be careful though since this also disables breaking on other situations where an exception crosses an AppDomain or managed/native boundary).